# What bicycle manufacturer used this emblem

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

The top bar has the model name "AMERICANO" but I don't know the name of the frame manufacturer. I would appreciate your help identifying it.
Thank you
[image]

Comment: Can you provide some photos of the whole bike? I've had no luck with the headtube badge, but I've found two brands with an Americano model, so a whole bike photo can either confirm or rule those out.

Comment: [Velobases head badge database](http://velobase.com/ListHeadBadges.aspx) is a useful resource.

Answer (score 10):

Your bike is a Scattante bicycle. They produce a model called the Americano and the logo can be seen in [this photo](https://p.globalsources.com/IMAGES/PDT/BIG/559/B1078183559.jpg) of a different Scattante bike.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all your comments that was very helpful in identifying my bike.